# Oracle - How to conditional SUM two rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have records like this:

```
|JOURNAL_NO|LINE_NO|AMOUNT|ACC_CODE|
|00001     |      1|  1800|562300C |
|00001     |      2|   900|562300C |
|00001     |      3|   450|562300C |
|00001     |   1001|   200|123222C |
|00001     |   1002|   100|123222C |
|00001     |   1003|    50|123222C |
|00002     |      1|  2700|562100C |
|00002     |      2|  4500|562100C |
|00002     |   1001|   300|123222C |
|00002     |   1002|   500|123222C |
```

How to SUM the AMOUNT, where LINE_NO 1 sum with LINE_NO 1001, LINE_NO 2 sum with LINE_NO 1002, etc.

This is the result that I want to achieve.

```
|JOURNAL_NO|LINE_NO|AMOUNT|ACC_CODE|
|00001     |      1|  2000|562300C |
|00001     |      2|  1000|562300C |
|00001     |      3|   500|562300C |
|00002     |      1|  3000|562100C |
|00002     |      2|  5000|562100C |
```

Comment: thanks @jarlh, but the LINE_NO is dynamic, so if the LINE_NO is 1-30 per journal_id, then it will also have LINE_NO 1001-1030.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a derived table where you use a case expression to adjust LINE_NO's > 1000.

```
select JOURNAL_NO, LINE_NO, SUM(AMOUNT), MAX(ACC_CODE)
from
(
select JOURNAL_NO,
       case when LINE_NO > 1000 then LINE_NO - 1000 else LINE_NO end as LINE_NO,
       AMOUNT, ACC_CODE
from tablename
) dt
group by JOURNAL_NO, LINE_NO
```

Comment: oh, thanks. I didn't realize if it can be used that way. Still new to the sql hehe.